# Networkx How to get length of a specific edge in multidigraph

Tags: python, graph, attributes, networkx, osmnx

**Hi, I download graph of drive_service from a place in France, and I am trying to get length of a specific edge.. is there anyway to do it ?**

```
import osmnx as ox

name_place = 'Aubervilliers, France'

graph_aubervillier = ox.graph_from_address( name_place ,network_type="drive_service")


graph_aubervillier[348206084][256242027]
```

> AtlasView({0: {'highway': 'residential', 'geometry': ,
>   'osmid': 31297114, 'junction': 'roundabout', 'oneway': True, 'length':
>   26.204}})

Comment: `graph_aubervillier[348206084][256242027]['length']` (someone else can probably give a bit more context to this response).

Comment: @Joel Not quite - I think the graph object is a MultiDiGraph, so you'd probably need `graph_aubervillier[348206084][256242027][0]['length']`. But if there are multiple edges between two nodes, better to iterate over it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `graph_aubervillier[348206084][256242027]`, you are returning all possible edges between those two nodes. Note that the graph is a MultiDiGraph, which can have multiple edges between two nodes.

So, if you want to get all lengths between two nodes, you need to iterate over the AtlasView object:

```
import osmnx as ox

name_place = 'Aubervilliers, France'

graph_aubervillier = ox.graph_from_address(name_place ,network_type="drive_service")

edges_of_interest = graph_aubervillier[348206084][256242027]

for edge in edges_of_interest.values():
    # May not have a length. Return None if this is the case.
    # Could save these to a new list, or do something else with them. Up to you.
    print(edge.get('length', None))
```

Comment: that's exaclty what I needed, Thanks ! :-)

Comment: If this solved your problem, you should upvote and accept this answer. :)

Comment: Andrew please I am a beginner .. for the same graph, I try to write it as shapefile with "nx.write_shp( graph_aubervillier ,  "pathfile/file1/file2 " ) " But it return an Error.. :/ this one : TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable   Do you know why ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure. Might be worth another question - make sure you post the full stack trace for the error. Have you had a look at the documentation for `write_shp` - https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/generated/networkx.readwrite.nx_shp.write_shp.html